--breakpoint flag changes the behaviour of mix test using bypass
Background
I am trying to do an integration test for a simple terminal application that I am writting.
This application is basically a Supervisor, which supervises other smaller libraries.
The communication within the project is mostly asynchronous, with processes sending messages to callers.
Problem
One of the tests I make requires an HTTP request, so I decided to use bypass for this. However, the problem is rather surprising to me. Here is the test:
    setup do
      bypass = Bypass.open(port: 8082)
      credentials = %{email: "an_email", pass: "a_password"}

      %{
        credentials: credentials,
        bypass: bypass
      }
    end


  test "logs in user correctly", %{bypass: bypass, credentials: credentials} do

      Bypass.expect_once(bypass, fn conn ->
        IO.inspect(conn.request_path, label: "REQ PATH")
        IO.inspect(conn.method, label: "METHOD")
        Plug.Conn.resp(conn, 429, ~s<{"errors": [{"code": 88, "message": "Rate limit exceeded"}]}>)
      end)

     # start the application
      _manager_pid = start_link_supervised!(ManagerSupervisor)
      
       # this should make a GET request to bypass but ...
       Manager.login(credentials, false)
    end

If I simply run mix test this simple test fails as Bypass received no requests.
1) test login logs in user correctly (Manager.WorkerTest)
     test/integration/manager_test.exs:83
     No HTTP request arrived at Bypass

Confusion
However, confunsingly enough, if I use the --breakpoints feature by running  iex -S mix test --breakpoints I can make the test pass by doing some simple steps:

Press n line by line.
When reaching the last line (Manager.login(credentials, false), I do not execute it with n or c. Instead I manually type the command Manager.login(credentials, false).
The call to bypass is made
Then I press c and the test passes

This is beyond confusing to me. It appears that the test process in not invoking Manager.login like it should.
I cannot explain this.
Questions

Why is the bypass being called when I invoke Manager.login manually using the --breakpoint option and not when mix test runs?
How can I fix my test?


I have never used bypass before. In my humble experience, when a test that does async IO fails when run normally but passes when run incrementally (line-by-line) the problem has to do with race conditions. Try adding Process.sleep(2000) before every statement in your test and see if it passes then. That will put 2 seconds between each "action", so it should "fix" possible race conditions. This is just to debug it. It's not good to leave Process.sleep in tests. You probably know that.

Solution
After more investigation I realized the test process running the test was finishing too fast. Turns out the delay for http requests to bypass and to other IO tasks the code had to do was taking too long, and so the test would end before the process running the test would receive any messages.
To this effect, even though the suggestion from @Peaceful James of using Process.sleep would work, I decided for a different approach, by using assert_receive which does have an option for a timeout, where it forces the test process to wait for a set amount of time, and then shows the processe's entire mailbox if no messages matching the given pattern were received.
The final test would look something like this:

  test "logs in user correctly", %{bypass: bypass, credentials: credentials} do

      Bypass.expect_once(bypass, fn conn ->
        Plug.Conn.resp(conn, 429, ~s<{"errors": [{"code": 88, "message": "Rate limit exceeded"}]}>)
      end)

      _manager_pid = start_link_supervised!(ManagerSupervisor)
      
       Manager.login(credentials, false)
       
       # 5 secs timeout
       assert_receive({:login, :ok}, 5000) 
    end

Credit to the original solution can be found in this post:
https://elixirforum.com/t/breakpoint-flag-changes-the-behaviour-of-mix-test-using-bypass/67138/2?u=fl4m3ph03n1x
